# How do i pass a PHP variable or session through nodeJS to socket.io on connection

Tags: php, node.js, ajax, mongodb, socket.io

I'm currently building a chat for my website which is built in PHP with MongoDB.

When the user Logs in i create Session variables for the user but can't seem to find a way to pass that variable through nodejs to socket.io.

I use this in the chat html page

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: *I need my php information here* });
```

Ajax defeats the purpose and is too slow.

Notes: i know i can pass with ajax on message but i'd prefer to pass on connection.

Im using this code in my server.js which makes it impossible for it to be .php file

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: you can add php code inside the javascript :
 <script>
var info="<?php  ..... ?>"
</script>

Comment: yeah but then i wont be able to do nodeJS sendfile cause the extension will be .php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your PHP information in a global Javascript variable. Something like

```
<script>var phpInfo = "<%= $yourInfo =>"</script>
```

( here the `<%=` stand for `<?php echo "" ?>` )
You can then use this variable into your connection

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: phpInfo });
```

This is not optimal but it works, Another way you could do that is retreive your info at some point (either then the user connect or when you load the main page) and save this into the HTML5 localStorage using `window.localStorage.setItem('phpInfo', phpinfo)` and then access this data using `window.localStorage.getItem('phpInfo')` 
This is a more elegent way to do it.

Comment: app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
the problem is im currently using socket.io script and it uses the following code cause the file extension will be .php

Comment: Then you should keep the data in the localStorage. Retreive it at some point and then use it when you need it.

Comment: i guess this seems to be the only way besides making a session with express. i will definitely give it a try.